# Understanding PayPal's REST API

Tags: php, api, paypal

A group of people that I work with need an easy invoicing system for our clients. We each have our own PayPal account.

We want to be able to generate invoices where the invoice will link to the PayPal account of the person who generated it. So for example, the invoice may just have a PayPal button that links to PayPal for the client to go pay. If I was to generate the invoice, that PayPal button would be linking to me so that I get the money. If my colleague generates the invoice, the PayPal button should link to him/her so that he/she gets the money. Finally, we also need to be able to retrieve the status of the invoice (paid / unpaid).

I have been reading over PayPal's API again and again, and I still don't understand how I can make something like this work. Would each of us have to generate our own API keys through PayPal to authenticate?

I downloaded a script that works where it doesn't even ask me for any API key or Secrets or Passwords. It just asks me for my PayPal email address, and somehow it works. It's even able to retrieve the status of the payment. Can someone give me advice on how to make this work?

EDIT: The script I downloaded does have an IPN Listener, but I'm still confused as to how it can retrieve the status of the PayPal payment just from my PayPal Email Address.

Comment: Please post again when you have an _actual_ programming issue.

Comment: @MartinBean This is a Q&A Community.. I asked a question. Please only comment on my questions when you have an actual answer to answer the question.

Comment: Comments are for comments. Answers are for answers. I had a comment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are a couple of options for an app like that.

1) Build the app as a service provider where you would use one set of API credentials (whoever owns the app) and then you'd have users of the system grant API permissions for your app to make API calls on their behalf.  Users can do this manually from within their own account or you could use the Permissions API.

2) Build the app with a settings panel where people can copy/paste their own API credentials into their user profile / settings page.  Then you would pull those API credentials to be used in the API request.

The Invoicing API will be the tool you're using to create the actual invoices, of course, and then IPN will indeed be what you use to update your system automatically when invoices are paid (or updated in any way.)

PayPal will return a "PayPal Invoice ID" and you can also pass in your own invoice ID if you have one from your own system.  Both of these will be returned in the IPN that gets sent when the invoice is paid, so you can easily update your system accordingly.